# How to recreate a vector without unnecessary copies C++

Tags: c++, vector, copy

I have a vector containing n complex objects. I want to perform a significant number of erasure, which would be extremely inefficient using [.erase()](https://cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/). The way I thought I would do it is by creating an empty vector on the heap, filling it with copies of objects that are to be kept, and redirecting the original vector towards the new one, **without a copy**. And of course free the old .data().

Something like this:

```
vector<Obj>* newVptr = new vector<Obj>;
newVptr->reserve(newSize);
int newId = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < oldSize; i++) {
   if (isKept(oldV[i])) {
      (*newVptr)[newId] = oldV[i];  // deep copy of Obj
      newId++;
   }
}
```

then free oldV's array (.data()) and replace the internal pointer with newVptr. How ?

I cant just discard oldV and keep going with newV, as it is an attribute of a class.

Comment: `std::vector` supports move semantics. See [constructor 8](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) here.

Comment: Don't use `new` to create a vector. A vector already manages a heap allocated array internally. Just create the second vector, insert whatever you need to insert and then move the new one to the old one.

Comment: Honestly, you are over-engineering this.  As mentioned, vector has move semantics.  Your attempt, if anything, will have either very minimal, or even detrimental effects as far as optimizations go.

Comment: Also, you can't use `vector::operator[]` to assign to non-existent objects that are merely pre-allocated with `vector::reserve()`. You need to use `vector::resize()` (or the `vector` constructor) instead to actually construct the objects before you can then assign to them. Otherwise, use `vector::push_back()` or `vector::emplace_back()` instead of `vector::operator[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's almost never a need to allocate a `std::vector` dynamically, as they allocate dynamically internally.

If you erase one-by-one, then that will be inefficient, yes. But the usual way to do this is using one of the `std::remove*` algorithms to move all the elements you want to keep to the front of the `vector`, and *then* call erase on the end.

For example:

```
oldV.erase(std::remove_if(oldV.begin(), oldV.end(), std::not_fn(isKept)),
           oldV.end());
```

Or in C++20:

```
std::erase_if(oldV, std::not_fn(isKept));
```

If you really want to copy the kept elements instead you could do:

```
std::vector<Obj> newV;
newV.reserve(oldV.size());
std::copy_if(oldV.begin(), oldV.end(), std::back_inserter(newV), isKept);
oldV = std::move(newV);
```

That `std::move` at the end would do the equivalent of your pointer swap idea.

Comment: I will try it thanks. For the dynamic allocation of the new one in my example, it must be done this way since it going out of context would destroy the array.

Comment: @Yeb02 That's the point, you **move** it to your original class member variable, before it gets destroyed. So no, you don't need `new` there.